# Kotlin - Force explicit type declarations in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

For readability purposes, I prefer to write...

```
val value: Int = 0
```

...rather than...

```
val value = 0
```

...but sometimes, I forget to add the type declaration, which leads to inconsistent code style.

Is there an option to enforce explicit type declarations?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57931935/how-can-i-make-intellij-force-me-to-specify-types-in-kotlin

Comment: Maybe this works.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57931935/how-can-i-make-intellij-force-me-to-specify-types-in-kotlin

Answer (score 0):

I would write a custom Detekt rule to check that.
There's also an IDE plugin for it and it highlights near real time.