# How can I make IntelliJ force me to specify types in Kotlin?

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

Kotlin supports type inference, so it is possible to type something like this:

`var x = 1`

But for me personally, if I forget to specify the type, then I sometimes lose track and have to come back around and add it anyway for clarity.

I would like to make my editor force me to specify the type, like this:

`var x: Int = 1`

Is it possible to do this? Is there any reason I would not want to do this?

Comment: _Side note:_ You can hover over a variable usage or function call and, if the control key (on Windows) is down, a popup will appear showing you the full signature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can go to `Preferences | Editor | Inspections`, search for `Public API declarations has implicit return type type`, tick `apply for internal` and `apply for private` options and set Error severity for this inspection.

[image]